# Mongo DB C# driver not throwing any exceptions even with wrong inputs

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5.2

I am setting everything wrong from connection string to database name but no exceptions thrown!

```
  const string ConnectionString = "mongodb://localhoszx";

    public IHttpActionResult Post(Lead data)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("x");
        IMongoCollection<Lead> leads = db.GetCollection<Lead>("Leads");
        leads.InsertOneAsync(data); }
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB C# driver is [async-only](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver).

With WebAPI, you have to mark your api in the "async way",returning `async Task<IHttpActionResult>` and call the mongo method with `await`